Aws Sagemaker restart server after extension installation
I am trying to migrate my extension to work on the new Aws Sagemaker experience.
after update my extension to Jupyterlab 4, I am trying to install it on lab instance.
The problem is that i cant find a way to restart my server after successfully installing  the extension (the ui lab plugin works and visible but the server extension returns 404).
what i was try:
restart-jupyter-server
this print:
Restarting the Jupyter server. This page should refresh in a few seconds. Note that any terminals will be closed.
If this page doesn't refresh after a few seconds, try reloading your browser window.
Restarting now...
but doesn't restart
